# How to find the equation to an ellipse with center at any arbitrary point?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I'm having hard time in learning the **Ellipse**. I'm using **The Elements of Coordinate Geometry** by **S.L. Loney** and his derivation of equation to an ellipse goes like this

> Let $ZK$ be the directrix, $S$ the focus, and let $SZ$ be perpendicular to the directrix

. [image]

> There will be a point $A$ on $SZ$ such that $$ SA = e\cdot AZ$$ Since, $e\lt1, $ there will be another point $A'$, in $ZS$ produced, such that $$ SA' = e\cdot A'Z$$ 
>   Let the the length of $AA'$ be called $2a$, and let $C$ be the middle point of $AA'$. Adding equations so formed, we have $$ 2a = AA' = e(AZ+A'Z)=2\cdot e \cdot CZ$$ i.e. $$ CZ= \frac{a}{e} $$ Subtracting the equations, we have $$ e(A'Z-AZ)=SA'-SA=(SC+CA')-(CA-CS)$$ 
>   i.e. $$e\cdot AA'=2CS$$ $$ CS = a\cdot e.$$ Let $C$ be the origin, $CA'$ the axis of x and a line through C perpendicular to AA' the axis of Y.
>   Let P be any point on the curve, whose coordinates are $x$ and $y$, and let PM be the perpendicular upon the directrix, and PN the perpendicular upon AA'.
>   The focus S is the point $(-ae,)$. 
>   The relation $SP^2= e^2 \cdot PM^2= e^2 \cdot ZN^2$ then gives $$ (x+ae)^2 +y^2 = e^2(x+\frac{a}{e})^2$$ $$x^2(1-e^2) +y^2 = a^2 (1-e^2)$$ $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2(1-e^2)} =1$$ if we put $$b= a\sqrt{1-e^2}$$ then we have $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1.$$

. As you can see, when he says *Let C be the origin* and this simplifies everything and because this only that we get a nice form like this $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1$$ I want to know how to find the equation to an ellipse if the center $C$ were to be at $(h,k)$.

Here is my try : Consider the coordinates of $C$ to be $(h,k)$ and the coordinates of $S$ to be $(p,q)$, since $CS$ is $a~e$, therefore $$ (p-h)^2 + (q-k)^2 = a^2~e^2$$ 
and similarly coordinates of $Z$ can be assumed to be $(c,d)$ and again $$ (c-h)^2 + (d-k)^2 =1 .$$ Now, let's turn to our sample point $P(x,y)$, by the definition of the ellipse: $$ SP^2 = e^2 PM^2 $$
$$ (p-x)^2 + (q-y)^2 = e^2 NZ^2 $$ and now comes the problem, I can't write $N$ as $(x,0)$ because $ZCZ'$ is no longer the $x-$axis. Why only in ellipse that we are getting this problem? It was so easy with circles and parabola but as soon as I have been introduced to ellipse I started getting problems. You, the equation of parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ tell us the opening is on the positive $x-$axis and it lies on $x-$axis and $x^2 = 4ay$ is just telling us that now everything is on $y-$ axis but in the case of ellipses it's we who have to determine how the eclipse would look like by comparing $a$ and $b$ (semi major and minor axis lengths). If we are given an equation like $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1 $$ and said that find the latus rectum then which formula should we use $\frac{2b^2}{a}$ or $\frac{2a^2}{b}$ (if in question it is given only $a$ and $b$ and not told which one is greater).

Thank you. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you were to take the time to type out the images. Some users cannot see images and so will not be able to help with your question. You can put a `>` in front of each line which will put it in a quote block, indicating that you are quoting directly from your source. You can then crop the first image down so that it is simply  the diagram.

Comment: @lioness99a Done. Now, I hope people will see it.

Comment: Looks good, thank you for doing that

Comment: Translating the center to $(h,k)$ is easy if you keep the axes of the ellipse parallel to cartesian axes (see answer below). But if you want point $S$ to have generic coordinates, then things get much more complicated. Anyway, you didn't take into account that $C$, $S$ and $Z$ are aligned.

Comment: Can someone tell me: why I'm not getting any answers for my question?

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x,y)=0$ is the equation of any set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $f(x-h,y-k)=0$ is the equation of the translation of that set by the vector $(h,k)$. Therefore an ellipse with center $(h,k)$ can be written as
$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1.$$

Comment: I have edited my question. So, please read it once. By the way your answer is very nice.